# Is it necessary to add an HP printer to CUPS using the hplip URI?

Tags: 12.04, server, printing, hplip

I recently setup a CUPS print server (Ubuntu server 12.04) and I having trouble with performance of a 
HP Color LaserJet Printer CP3505n. The printer pauses for about a second
between printing each page, which is annoying when there is a lot of
printing to be done. This doesn't happen when the printer is installed directly
to a Windows client.

In an attempt to fix this I have setup the printer a couple different ways.  I decided *not* to do 
a Samba share since this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS_printer_sharing) said IPP is preferred.

**First Method**

- Added to HP LaserJet to  CUPS as a *Discovered Network Printer*, and selected
  `HP Color LaserJet cp3505 hpijs pcl3, 3.12.2 (en)` driver.  I did not use a hplip URI.

**Second Method (hplip URI)**

- I thought adding hplip to the mix might improve the performance, so I  added
  the printer like this:

  - Ran `hp-setup -m 192.168.2.60`,
  - *prompted to select driver*

    Selected `HP Color LaserJet cp3505 hpijs pcl3, 3.12.2 (en)`
  - Used hplip to generate a URI: `hp-makeuri 192.168.2.60`
  - Then added the printer to CUPS as a *Local Printer:  HP Printer (HPLIP)*, and entered:
    `hp:/net/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP3505?ip=192.168.2.60`.

Either method I use I am able to share the printer on the network by adding a printer as
`http://192.168.2.2:631/printers/HP_LASER-TERRAC`.

- Does it make a difference which way the printer is added cups?

  If so, and I install the printer with the hp URI, can I still change the driver using the CUPS web interface? I have been trying out different drivers to try and improve performance, and the cups interface is the easiest way to change them.

  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know hpijs will be deprecated, so I would not recommend using it. For some reason hplip software tries to use the deprecated package by default in some installs. Check [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/777670) bug report in launchpad.

You can try to dowload manually the hp driver from their website, extract the package and select the PID file manually from the extracted folder.

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend some alternative drivers?